# How to create SAS .XPT without SAS server

Tags: oracle, plsql, sas

I have to export data into SAS .XPT files using PLSQL, without any third party drivers or SAS server support.

Comment: Any documentation on what the XPT file format looks like?  Is this a text file format?  Or binary?  If it's binary, you're probably looking for a third party library.  If something like that exists, I would expect that it would be a Java library that could be loaded into Oracle as a Java stored procedure.

Comment: Why?  Seems like a silly restriction.  The V5 Transport format is public, but it only supports 8 character variable names and character variables are limited to 200 characters.  The CPORT format is not public and varies from version to version of SAS.

Comment: Hi Tom.  Thanks for comment.  I am completely new to SAS application.  Can you please provide any documentation details.